# Actor addresses and tests

Tags: scala, akka

I'm building up an actor hierarchy in which some actors reply to messages they get directly to a well-known actor (fixed name). I.e. these actors (far-removed in the hierarchy) obtain an actorRef via `context.actorFor("akka://...")`.

I.e. for example, I have an "orchestrating" actor:

system.actorOf(Props[OrchestratingActor], name = "orchestrator")

which will then have an address of the kind `akka://application/user/orchestrator`

and someplace else, a random worker that received a message and wants to talk to the orchestrator:

```
class RandomWorker extends Actor {
  def theOrchestrator = context.actorFor("akka://application/user/orchestrator")
  def receive = {
    case Foo =>
      theOrchestrator ! "Bar"
  }
}
```

Now, I'd like to test those actors and am wondering about how to deal with those addresses: when unit-testing an actor (e.g. using TestActorRef), how do I go about checking what's being sent to the remote address? One idea would be to (when possible) provide the address to the well-known actor via the constructor, and pass in the address of a TestActor to see what's being received. However I wonder if there isn't a way to "impersonate" a given address in the test, esp. in situation where the addresses aren't simple.

In other words I'd like to test the behavior of the actor (will it indeed have sent `"Bar"` to the orchestrator upon receiving a `Foo`

Comment: I am sorry but I do not understand the question at all. Can you make a list of what you have and what you want?

Comment: Indeed, this was a bit fluffy, I hope it's clearer now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My recommendation would be to avoid using look-ups of actors for the purpose you show. It is rather a tool for the setup phase of your application, when wiring it all together. But even then most actors’ supervisors will know the dependencies of their children without using look-ups.

Within a local actor system all ActorRefs can be injected top to bottom (using constructor arguments or introduction messages). Look-ups are most useful when introducing remote systems with each other.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with injecting the address via the constructor. Let it me know if you need any details, because at the moment I don't know how to make this more clear, since you basically answered your own question. And btw, I don't know, which Akka version you are using, but `actorFor` has been recently deprecated in favor of `ActorSelection`, and there are good reasons for this.